# How to export XFBML from another page?

Tags: xfbml

It is possible to store Open Graph Tags on another page?

Like:

```
<meta src="myinfo.xml">
```

I have only one HTML page that contains slideshows and want to pass different parameters to each image.

Do not want to pollute the code with various metadata.